# Intersection of sets within space [0,1/i] vs (0,1/i) as i approaches infinity

Tags: probability, statistics, interval-arithmetic

[Here's an example from All of Statistics by Wasserman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On4zm.png)

[image]

So when A includes 0, the intersection is just 0, but when it only approaches 0, the intersection is the empty set.

Why is this? Is there a name to describe this property, so I can read more about it? I can visualize why, but I'd like to know the formal terms to describe it.

Comment: From the title of your question, perhaps you are looking for the statement that the [*"infinite intersection of nested non-empty closed subsets of a compact space is not empty"*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337397) or something similar involving nested bounded closed sets  for $\bigcap_i \left[0,\frac1i \right] \not = \emptyset$.  Meanwhile $\left(0,\frac1i \right)$ is not closed so does not have this property

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, for any positive number $x$ pick an $i>\frac{1}{x}$. Then it will follow that $\frac{1}{i}<x$ so $x$ cannot lie in the intersection since in does not lie in $\left(0,\frac{1}{i}\right)$. So no positive number lies in the intersection.

In the first case, $0$ lies in each set, so it lies in the intersection. But by the argument above, no positive $x$ can lie in the intersection.