# The infinite intersection of (0,1/i] where i starts at 1

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So here is the problem,

$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (0,\frac1i]$

personly I think the answer is either $0$ or $0^+$.

The answer is supposedly $\emptyset$.

I came here because I can't seem to prove it to my self that it's the empty set. I also couldn't find any info on this particular problem only problems like it [Intersection of sets within space [0,1/i] vs (0,1/i) as i approaches infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482296/intersection-of-sets-within-space-0-1-i-vs-0-1-i-as-i-approaches-infinity).

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is $0^+$? Notice that $0$ isn't actually in *any* of this family of sets.

Comment: I see $0^+$ as a value approaching $0$ from the positive side but not zero, at least that's my thought.

Comment: There are no infinitesimals in $\mathbb{R}$, so there is no minimum positive number. So there is no $0^+$.

Comment: For 0 to be in the intersection, it would have to be in every one of the intervals $\left(0, \frac1n\right]$. But it isn't in any of them!

Answer (score 3):

Note that each set only contains positive numbers, so the intersection must also only contain positive numbers.

Now suppose we conjecture that $k>0$ is in the intersection. By the archimedian property, we can find $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>\frac1k$. This implies $\frac1n<k$, so $k\notin(0,\frac1n]$, a contradiction.

Hence the intersection is empty.