# Zorn's lemma: Given a non-empty, closed, convex set E in Hilbert space $\mathrm{H},$ it must obtain a unique element of smallest norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given a non-empty, closed, convex set E in Hilbert space $\mathrm{H},$ it must obtain a unique element of smallest norm.

A classic proof is use parallelogram law. But I want to show this using Zorn's lemma directly. Say let $P$ be set of all closed balls that intersects with $E$. Define ordering as containment of the balls. For each chain, an upper bound can be intersection of all the balls in this chain because intersection of all balls with $E$ is still non-empty ([Show that the infinite intersection of nested non-empty closed subsets of a compact space is not empty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337397/show-that-the-infinite-intersection-of-nested-non-empty-closed-subsets-of-a-comp)). This gives existence of a maximal element: the smallest ball that has non-empty intersection with $E$. But this does not even uses completeness. Where went wrong? Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Compact metric spaces are complete, so the link would use completeness. However, closed balls in a Hilbert space (but you could say normed space) of infinite dimension are never compact (except the points).

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you. I get the first point. But why "balls in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space are never compact"? The ball must be bounded and contain all limit points due to completeness assumption of Hilbert space, right?

Comment: It is closed and bounded, but [Riesz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) implies that in an infinite-dimensional normed space there is always a sequence of vectors $\{v_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $\lVert v_t\rVert<1$ for all $t$ and such that $\lVert v_n-v_m\rVert>\frac12$ for all $n\ne m$.

Comment: A possible method... closed convex sets in Hilbert space are weakly closed. So closed bounded convex sets are weakly compact.  Can we use a finite intersection property on these?

Comment: @GEdgar Ah, yes, that works. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but nothing ensures that $E$ is compact. For example, let $E$ be the closed unit ball of your Hilbert space. Then it is non-empty, closed and convex, but non-compact when $H$ is infinite-dimensional. Hence, your argument with the finite-intersection property is flawed.