# Problems regarding the denseness of $a\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: analysis, contest-math, compactness, additive-combinatorics

I came across a problem related to the denseness of $a\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}$. Explicitly, the problem asks:

> Let $a$ be irrational.
> (a) For any  $y \in [0,1]$, prove that there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\{na\} \in [y-\epsilon, y+\epsilon]$.
>
> (b) Prove that there exists $b \in [0,1]$ such that there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\{na\} \in [b-9^{-n}, b+9^{-n}]$.

Where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$. This is a contest problem ([Bulgaria EGMO TST](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3253220p29865602)). Being always interested in analysis, I tried solving the problem. This is my attempt:

> Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of $x$. We choose $n$ big enough so $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$. For $k=0,1,...,n$, we let
> $$ x_k = \{ka \} $$
> Divide $[0,1)$ into $n$ equal intervals, then two $x_i, x_j (i<j)$ falls in the same interval, so $|\{(i-j)a\}| < \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$. That is, there exists $p = j-i < n$ and $q$ so that $$ |pa - q | < \epsilon.$$ This proves the Dirichlet's approximation theorem.
>
> In fact, an implication of which is that $\{na\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, as $a \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}$ as an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ has no least positive element. In particular, for any $y \in (0, 1)$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there are $na$ whose fractional part is in $[y-\epsilon, y+\epsilon]$. If $y$ is never a fractional part of a multiple of $a$ (that is, $y \notin a \mathbb{Z} +\mathbb{Z}$), then we choose $\epsilon \to 0$ to achieve infinite of such $n$. If $y$ is a fractional part of multiple of $a$, then we can choose $|y' - y| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ such that $y' \notin a\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}$ (otherwise $[y-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, y+\frac{\epsilon}{2}] \subseteq a \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}$, which is absurd by cardinality), then again choosing $\epsilon \to 0$ gives infinite of such $n$. For $y=0, 1$, similar discussions work. This finishes (a).

But I'm stuck for (b). Namely, to construct $b \in [0,1]$ so that $\{na\} \in [b-9^{-n}, b+9^{-n}]$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The negation of this statement is that any $b \in [0,1]$ satisfy that $\{na\} \in [b-9^{-n}, b+9^{-n}]$ for only finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So there's $N_b$ satisfying $n \geq N_b \implies \{na\} \notin [b-9^{-n}, b+9^{-n}]$. We let such $N_b$ be minimal. Note that, then, $N_b$ don't have a uniform bound for $b \in [0,1]$. So for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find $b$ s.t. $N_b > k$. This implies $\{na\} \in [b-9^{-n}, b+9^{-n}]$ for some $n < N_b$ (which isn't useful as $N_b$ could be big). I tried using Bolzano-Weierstrass,  and make no progress since.

The aops website mentioned theorem of nested intervals (compact sets?), but I don't quite get it. Any other hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Most olympiads such as this are for high school students. Are said students expected to solve problems which are straight up from analysis?

Comment: @Sahaj In very rare occasions like this one, sometimes yes. Some team selection problem were made by previous contestants, and some of them do occasionally make these kinds of problem. Again, this kind of problem is very rare though.

Answer (score 1):

[Since $\{ n\alpha \}$ is dense in $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903142/for-an-irrational-number-a-the-fractional-part-of-na-for-n-in-mathbb-n-is), Part $(a)$ is almost obvious.

For Part $(b)$, let's assume:

$$B_1=[\{m_1\alpha\} -\frac{1}{9^{m_1}}, \{m_1\alpha\} +\frac{1}{9^{m_1}}],$$

where $m_1 \in \mathbb N.$ It's easy to choose $m_1$ such that $B_1 \subset [0,1]$ as we will see a similar reasoning in the following.

Take $b^* \in B_1$  and $\epsilon >0 $ such that:

$$[b^*-\epsilon,b^*-\epsilon] \subset B_1=[\{m_1\alpha\} -\frac{1}{9^{m_1}}, \{m_1\alpha\} +\frac{1}{9^{m_1}}].$$

By Part $(a)$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $\{na\} \in [b^*-\frac{\epsilon}{2},b^*-\frac{\epsilon}{2}].$ Pick such a sufficiently large $n$, say $m_2$, such that:

$$[\{m_2\alpha\} -\frac{1}{9^{m_2}}, \{m_2\alpha\} +\frac{1}{9^{m_2}}] \subset [b^*-\epsilon,b^*-\epsilon] .$$

Hence, we have:

$$B_2=[\{m_2\alpha\} -\frac{1}{9^{m_2}}, \{m_2\alpha\} +\frac{1}{9^{m_2}}] \subset [\{m_1\alpha\} -\frac{1}{9^{m_1}}, \{m_1\alpha\} +\frac{1}{9^{m_1}}]=B_1.$$

Doing the same procedure infinitely many times, we will obtain the chain:

$$[0,1] \supset B_1 \supset B_2 \supset B_3 \supset ...  \ .$$

Let's consider $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$, [which is not empty.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337397/show-that-the-infinite-intersection-of-nested-non-empty-closed-subsets-of-a-comp) Now, it's easy to see that every element of $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$ works as the desired $b$ in the question.